Getting directory from environment variable, with fallback to working directory
In an Elixir program, I want to get the path of a certain directory from the environment variable V, and as a fallback (if the variable is empty) use the working directory instead. I came up with the following solution, which looks overly complicated to me:
dirpath = System.get_env("V") || (File.cwd |> elem(1))

The reason for this construct is that File.cwd returns a tuple, where the second element is the actual path, instead just the string of the working directory itself (which would be more natural to me).
Is my approach really the way an experienced Elixir programmer would do it? I'm coming from Ruby programming, and in Ruby I would simply write dirpath=ENV['V']||Dir.pwd, but I guess I'm still thinking too much in the Ruby way when writing Elixir scripts.

"Is my approach really the way an experienced Elixir programmer would do it?" It depends what you're doing. What's in the directory?

@AdamMillerchip. A couple of files, which later will be opened. First I calculate the "base directory", and then I know how I find all the files below. The base directory is often specified via an environment variable, but I don't want to require the user of my script to set this variable, so I use the PWD as a fallback. This is the general policy for all our scripts; it's just that I now, for educational purpose, try to write one in Elixir instead of one of the language I'm proficient in. Why is the directory content important for my question?

Oh ok. Just because serving files from a web server is the most common case so I wanted to rule that out.

@AdamMillerchip : I'm a bit surprised by this statement. Is this something specific for Elixir, that the language is mostly used for fetching data over the web? I see it as general purpose programming language, and all programs I wrote so far (mostly in Ruby, Perl, C or shell scripting) had the property, that the vast number of input to my programs came from files which are local, or at least accessible via i.e. NFS. Getting something via something like http or soap, does happen, but would certainly not count as "most common case".

I just found that there is also a function File.cwd!, which returns the wd as a string. Hence I can do a
dirpath = System.get_env("V") || File.cwd!

